Physical Process of conversion of energy in excited states to thermal energy
In Optics, Eugene Hecht writes:
On the other hand, if the photon’s energy matches that of one of the excited states, the atom will absorb the light, making a quantum jump to that higher energy level. In the dense atomic landscape of ordinary gases (at pressures of about 102 Pa and up), solids, and liquids, it’s, very likely that this excitation energy will rapidly be transferred, via collisions, to random atomic motion, thermal energy, before a photon can be emitted.
The excitation energy is quantized, it cannot be given in any arbitrary amount to other particles on collision (whatever collision means at this microscopic level). So how does this conversion of energy actually happens?

re: "excitation energy is quantized, it cannot be given in any arbitrary amount to other particles on collision", there do exist some slack mechanism which converts imprecise excesses in energy into momentum. If excess energy is too great, the collision switches automatically to a different outcome (e.g. photoelectric effect becomes Thompson/Compton scattering) which again has some tolerance for different collision energies. The process switches again to photofission if collision energy is even greater, so nature seems to come well-prepared for any amount of collision energy one throws at it.

@James can you refer me to some sources?

Wikipedia has articles on individual processes, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect . The connection to thermal energy should come from the momentum which causes random collisions in the many body system.
